# How to move JQuery Tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I have a JQuery Tooltip when user hover to the "Do Not User" div, the problem is the tool tip was cut, It looks like it's behind the "Show Only Assets" links. Is there any CSS attribute to fix this bug?

```
<div data-toggle="tooltip" class="dnu_Tooltip" title="For reasons of security due to IP restrictions or vulnerabilities Avanade does not recommend the use of this product">
    <div class="doNotUseFlag text-center">
        Do not Use
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.dnu_Tooltip + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```js
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

Comment: add a higher z-index

Comment: @simpleProgrammer can you make a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you using bootstrap? if yes, just add this on your div tag **data-placement="left/right/top/bottom"** add this on your div tag.

Comment: I moved it on the left side, works with my problem, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `z-index`

```
.dnu_Tooltip + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```